# Dataframe row/column calculations [cell dependency]

Tags: pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, shift

| Year | PresentValue | InterestRateChange | ShortTermRates | CouponRates | LoanRates | DeltaPrice | CouponEarning | LoanPayment | Earnings/Loss | FinalPresentValue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1991 | 2.000000e+10 | -0.005 | 0.060 | 0.085 | 0.070 | 1.000000e+09 | 1.700000e+09 | -875000000.0 | 1.825000e+09 | 2.182500e+10 |
| 1992 | NaN | -0.005 | 0.055 | 0.080 | 0.065 | NaN | NaN | -812500000.0 | NaN | NaN |
| 1993 | NaN | -0.005 | 0.050 | 0.075 | 0.060 | NaN | NaN | -750000000.0 | NaN | NaN |
| 1994 | NaN | -0.005 | 0.045 | 0.070 | 0.055 | NaN | NaN | -687500000.0 | NaN | NaN |
| 1995 | NaN | 0.020 | 0.040 | 0.065 | 0.050 | NaN | NaN | -625000000.0 | NaN | NaN |
| 1996 | NaN | 0.020 | 0.060 | 0.085 | 0.070 | NaN | NaN | -875000000.0 | NaN | NaN |

I have the following table in a pandas DataFrame, as you might notice there are some columns which consist of NaN cells. Those cells are dependent on the output of another cell.

E.g. the column 'PresentValue', in order to fill in the second sell i would have to take the first value in the column 'FinalPresentValue', and in second cell in the column 'CouponEarning' I would have to multiple the recently calculated second value in the column 'PresentValue' with the second value in the column 'CouponRates' etc, etc.

How can i fill in the table without tedious and repetitive coding?
I would really appreciate any suggestions on how I might go about this.

Here's my code so far:

```
Initial_Investment = 7.5 * 10**9 # 10^9 ~ 1 Billion
Initial_Loan = 12.5 * 10**9
Initial_Portfolio_Value = 20 * 10**9 
Portfolio_Duration = 10 # Macaulay Duration 
Initial_Short_Term_Rate = 0.06
Initial_Coupon_Rate = 0.085 
Initial_Loan_Rate = 0.07

years = np.arange(1991,1997,1) # 1991-1996
interest_rate_change = np.array([-0.005, -0.005, -0.005, -0.005, 0.02, 0.02]) # 0.005 ~ 0.5%
present_value = np.array([Initial_Portfolio_Value, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN])

df = pd.DataFrame({'Year':years, 'PresentValue':present_value, 'InterestRateChange':interest_rate_change})

df['ShortTermRates'] = df['InterestRateChange'].shift(1,fill_value=Initial_Short_Term_Rate).cumsum()
df['CouponRates'] = df['InterestRateChange'].shift(1,fill_value=Initial_Coupon_Rate).cumsum()
df['LoanRates'] = df['InterestRateChange'].shift(1,fill_value=Initial_Loan_Rate).cumsum()
df['DeltaPrice'] = df.InterestRateChange * df.PresentValue * -Portfolio_Duration
df['CouponEarning'] = df.CouponRates * df.PresentValue 
df['LoanPayment'] = df.LoanRates * -Initial_Loan
df['Earnings/Loss'] = df.DeltaPrice + df.CouponEarning + df.LoanPayment
df['FinalPresentValue'] = df.PresentValue + df['Earnings/Loss']
df
```

Answer (score 0):

To replace NaN value in PresentValue Column you can take average of PresentValue and replace it with NaN

Since other column values are different the Final Output value calculated will be different and there won't be any problem

Also the **diversified data will be generated if you replace mean with Nan**

But since PresentValue is primary key it should not contain NaN value(Just a observation)

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.